# How is desktop notification implemented in chat.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, chat

How has the desktop notification in chat.stackoverflow.com been implemented?

Comment: I think only **`balpha`** can answer it :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It uses [the Web Notifications API](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/). WebKit-based browsers already implement a vendor-prefixed version of it, i.e. `window.webkitNotifications`.

Fun fact: in Mountain Lion’s Safari 6, Web Notifications get displayed in Notification Center.

See [browser support](http://caniuse.com/notifications) and [some more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2350124/96656).

Comment: Not sure if i.e. = Internet Explorer or For Example.

Comment: @Xaade, it’s neither. [_i.e._ = _id est_, meaning _that is_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I.e.#id_est). IE is Internet Explorer.