# Desktop notification on chat not working in Safari

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, notifications, safari

I found this cool desktop notification feature in the stackoverflow chat.

When I click *"enable desktop notification"* it says *"Desktop notification is blocked by your browser; [help me with this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/help/desktop-notifications)"*. There is no help for Safari. I allowed notifications for chat.stackoverflow.com in the settings. The notifications should appear in the OS X notification center ...

I'm using Safari 6 on OS X 10.8.1.

It's seems to work in Chrome, but not in Safari.

Comment: Safari 6 [isn't officially supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: Hmm, according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143727/115866 it's supposed to be working in Safari 6.

Comment: @Rory Safari 6 is not a beta release, nor a dev release.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but I just had a coworker confirm that it's working fine for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Safari 6 on OS X 10.8.1, and I get the notifications from chat. As far as I recall, it didn't happen immediately when I clicked on "Enable desktop notification"; it happened some minutes later, or when I exit any chat room, and returned.

I also tried disabling the notification messages, to immediately re-enable them, but I didn't get any error message.

Comment: It worked for me finally, after I relaunched Safari.